# iPod touch/iPhone app stuck on Splash Screen in iOS 6, but works fine in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, ipod

My app is developed for the 4th generation iPod touch to work with a custom dock for audio analysis. The app can also runs without being connected to the dock. So with iOS 5 and 4.3, it works fine whether the device (the iPod touch) is connected to the dock or not. Now with iOS 6, it works fine if the device is not connected to the dock, but if I connected the device to the dock and run the app, the app SOMETIMES stuck on the splash screen and terminates after seconds (sometimes a second later, sometimes more than 10 seconds later).

How would you debug this kind of issues?

One thing I know is that when an app tries to load data at start up and if it takes too long to load the data, the system terminates the app. I don't believe that is happening here because the same app works fine on iOS 5 whether the device is plugged in to the dock or not.

Dev environment: xcode 4.5.2, Mountain Lion 10.8.2, 4th generation iPod touch

Thanks

Comment: Once the app has crashed you should be able to see the crash dumps using XCode? Have you tried debugging it over WiFi?

Comment: Check if you are using any methods that were deprecated in iOS 6.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness thanks a lot for the suggestion. I used the crash report to figure out the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Can I add my suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness ya, you may add your suggestion as an answer. I learned a lot going that route. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the app has crashed you should be able to see the crash dumps using XCode. These crash dumps should point you in the first direction.

As you're using the dock, you can debug it over WiFi if necessary.